# Different Queries Results to one Row

Tags: sql-server

I am writing three different query and want there result as all in single row

example :

```
SELECT top 1 processdate as gold FROM goldchart WHERE instrument = 'gold'
   order by processdate desc

SELECT top 1 processdate as silver FROM silverchart WHERE instrument = 'silver'
   order by processdate desc

SELECT top 1 processdate as usoil FROM usoilchart WHERE instrument = 'usoil'
   order by processdate desc
```

The result i am getting is :

```
gold
2014-04-10
silver
2014-01-11
usoil
2014-02-14

The result i need is :

gold        silver       usoil 
2014-04-10  2014-01-11   2014-02-14
```

Need to Combine all the three queries and get the result as one single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap the select statements in parenthesis and group them together

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT top 1 processdate FROM goldchart WHERE instrument = 'gold'
  order by processdate desc) as gold,

 (SELECT top 1 processdate FROM silverchart WHERE instrument = 'silver'
  order by processdate desc) as silver,

(SELECT top 1 processdate FROM usoilchart WHERE instrument = 'usoil'
  order by processdate desc) as usoil
```

Answer (score 1):

I think SQL server allows you do do this w/o a from...

```
Select 
(SELECT top 1 processdate FROM goldchart WHERE instrument = 'gold' order by processdate desc) as gold, 
(SELECT top 1 processdate FROM silverchart WHERE instrument = 'silver' order by processdate desc) as silver, 
(SELECT top 1 processdate FROM usoilchart WHERE instrument = 'usoil' order by processdate desc) as usoil
```

Answer (score 0):

this works, at least on SQLServer.

```
SELECT TOP 1 gc.processdate AS gold, sc.processdate AS silver, uc.processdate AS usoil 

FROM goldchart gc, silverchart sc, usoilchart uc 

ORDER BY gc.processdate DESC, sc.processdate DESC, uc.processdate DESC
```